# Sublime Text 3 double tab bug

Tags: arrays, tabs, double, sublimetext3

I've been using Sublime Text 3 for a week and i love it so far but i came across an annoying bug? Basically when i paste in this big array:

http://pastebin.com/sA5DNFaw

My tab size doubles so instead of 4 it does 8 spaces. Even if i delete the array the tab size stays the same. I tried deleting everything in the file and reloading Sublime but the issue persists.

Does someone know how to fix this? Or what causes it?

Thank you.

Comment: To those who voted to close: from [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the [help], software questions are allowed if they cover "*[...] software tools commonly used by programmers*". Sublime Text, like vim, emacs, Notepad++, etc., is a programming editor, and there are [tens of thousands of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext2+or+sublimetext3+or+sublimetext+or+vim+or+vi+or+emacs+or+notepad%2b%2b) about them on this site that are perfectly on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug. Go to `Preferences --> Settings - User` and add this line: 
 `"detect_indentation": false,`. Your Settings should looks something like this:

```
{
   "detect_indentation": false,
}
```

It shouldn't change your indentation settings anymore but if you still have 8 spaces you can:

1. Select all code.
2. Convert Indentation to Tabs.
3. Tab Width: 4.
4. Convert Indentation to Spaces.

Comment: Everything works great now, thanks!